# Deactivate agent app after launch in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsapplication

What method should be called to deactivate an app right after it's launch in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` delegate method has been called? Or maybe there is a better place to do that? The documentation for `deactivate` method for `NSApplication` says that I shouldn't call this method directly since AppKit knows better how to deactivate stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using `-[NSApplication hide:]` would work, or perhaps activate another app using `-[NSRunningApplication activateWithOptions:]` (10.6 only, tho).  However, I don't foresee many problems with using `deactivate:`.

Comment: I think i'll try with NSRunningApplication approach. Thanks a heap!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

You can use `-hide:` to deactivate your app.  I also wouldn't hesitate using `-deactivate` if it actually does what you need.  It's just that *normal* applications do not explicitly deactivate themselves; I think that's what the documentation is saying.

However, if you set `LSUIElement` in Info.plist your application should not become active when launched; it also won't have a menu bar or dock icon.

Comment: App does become active after launch, since I added global event monitor and i get beeps each time i press the global key registered in global event monitor.

Global event monitors don't route events to the app while it's being active. Right?